# Which is correct - you or your in this context?

Tags: pronouns, possessives

> Your staring won’t make me walk faster

or

> You staring won’t make me walk faster

Which is correct, *you* or *your*?

Comment: Both are technically "correct".  It's a matter of choice/context.

Comment: The second is incorrect, as the "staring" is an adjective, which shouldn't be placed directly after pronoun without a verb.

Comment: @r13 - How is "staring" an adjective?

Comment: Similar to the sentence "It’s amazing that the university student is only 16.", note the "is" after "it". In your case, "are" should follow "You", but then, the sentence does not make sense. You can check dictionary on the definition and use of word in the form verb+ing.

Comment: Native speakers (at least in the US) routinely use both constructions.  I have some vague and unreliable memory of a grammar teacher stating that "your" is the correct choice here, but pay no attention to that.

Comment: Both are correct, second is more colloquial; it is similar to “you staring at me?” which means “(are) you staring at me?”. It is missing the “be” verb but as r13 said in an earlier comment, if you add *be* to the second sentence it won’t make sense. Context, context, context.

Comment: @Hot Licks The present participle (VERB+ing) is also used as an adjective.

Comment: @r13 - Not in the above context.

Comment: @Hot Licks Is "She jumping up and down" correct?

Comment: @Hot Licks So, what is in the above context, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: @Hot Licks This is from the Cambridge Dictionary: "STARING" - adjective. For the second sentence, can you say it is the "present participle" without verb before the gerund ?

Comment: All people say "both are correct" should call their English teacher to schedule a refreshment class :)

Comment: @r13 "Staring" here is a gerund (and therefore acts as a noun) in the first example and a verb (present participle and having for its actor "you") in the second.

Answer (score 2):

"Your staring won’t make me walk faster" It presents an action that could or going to happen.
"You staring won’t make me walk faster" While this action it's happening right now. So, both ways are correct, it depends only on context.

Comment: There really isn't any difference in meaning. Some people will maintain there is, and follow their own rules. But nobody agrees on the rules, since they're so vague and have to do with what is meant instead of which words are used.

Comment: It is not the "meaning" matters, it is the grammar, either correct, or not correct, both in speaking and writing.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are correct .
The first one is in the possessive gerund , more formal and grammatically correct .
The second one is also correct and it is in the accusative gerund .

However, it is preffered to use the first one in Grammar , whereas there are cases when the second one is preffered over the first one , namely when the there is a  balanced sentence as : "THEY OBJECTED TO **TOM** ( instead of Tom´s ) GETTING NOTHING AND **JOHN** ( instead of John´s )  EVERYTHING "

Answer (score -6):

Content below responds to your question indirectly. It also promote understanding on the proper order of the English language (*Noun/Pronoun + Verb*).

**Basic word order in English**
The basic word order of an English sentence is **Subject + Predicate**.

The predicate is the part of the sentence that tells something about the subject. The predicate always includes the verb.

So, Subject + Predicate word order can be broken down into smaller pieces like this:

**subject + verb**

Or

**subject + verb + object**

Let's review the definitions of these parts of speech.
**subject = noun or pronoun**

The person, place, or thing that the sentence is about.

**verb = action or state of being**

one verb or a verb phrase

object = the noun or nouns that receives the action of the verb or is affected by the action of the verb

Unlike some languages, English usually requires you to put the subject near the beginning of the sentence before the verb. Native speakers rarely stray from this word order in correct English.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Your" is the second person possessive adjective. It is used to describe something as belonging to someone. It should be followed by either a noun or the gerund.             "you are." is usually followed by the present participle, but can also be followed by an adjective.