# Is personal pronoun followed with "verb+ing" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs, pronouns

Is the sentence below correct? What type of pronoun is "You" in this case?

**You staring** won’t make me walk faster

Below is the result from an online grammar check on the sentence as shown:

[image]

Explanation and example sentences:

[image]

Your comments?

Comment: This looks like a semi-duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563890/which-is-correct-you-or-your-in-this-context

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122749/discussion-on-question-by-r13-is-personal-pronoun-followed-with-verbing-gramm).